# Find content inside parentheses and the word that comes before it (OpenRefine)

Tags: regex, data-cleaning, openrefine, grel

I'm trying to extract some text from a column on a CSV file. Here is an example:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (2015), consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua (2000)."

I wanna get a new column with "amet (2015)" and "aliqua (2000)". This expression gives me the (2015) and (2000): value.find(/(.*?)/)

But how can I also get the word before the parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

here is the regex your are looking for `/\w* \([^\)]*\)/gm`.